# Creating new table rows with data using php

Tags: php

I have a table that is populated with php via a text file. I know how to create a new table for each new data entry but I am trying to just create a new row instead of a whole new table. How can I create a new row with data instead of an entire table?

This is currently what I have now and I just want to create a new row with the variables in it. How can I achive this without it creating a whole new table each time. I have tried a couple of things with no success.

```
$tracreport = $tracreport . "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-top:15px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;'>
            <tr>
                <td style='padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px; font-size: .9em; text-align: center; color: #00FF00;'> Tracking " . $tnumber[1] . " active storm cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table id='tracReport' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Cell ID</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Tracking Since</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Bearing</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Distance</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Intensity</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Trend</td>
                                <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Last Strike</td
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tid[$k] . "</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdtime[$k] . "</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdirection[$k] . "  &deg;</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdistance[$k] . " miles</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . strtolower($tintensity[$k]) . "</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" .  trim(strtolower($ttrend[$k])) . "</td>
                                <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" .  trim(strtolower($tactivity[$k])) . "</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
```

Comment: Can you show how you are building this table? It looks like you just need to split your current table into 3 variable - table start, rows that you want to duplicate, and table end. Then you can do a loop - for,foreach,while - and build/add as many rows as you want.

Comment: The table is in my original post. Can you show me an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Which row is it that you want to repeat? Is it the internal one, in `<table id='tracReport'>`, or is it the outer one with `Tracking " . $tnumber[1]`?

Comment: It is in the internal one. The row that has the variables in the table cells. Just that row of cells though, not the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try splitting your table, and add your loop in the middle

```
// begin your table
$tracreport = $tracreport . "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-top:15px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px; font-size: .9em; text-align: center; color: #00FF00;'> Tracking " . $tnumber[1] . " active storm cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table id='tracReport' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Cell ID</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Tracking Since</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Bearing</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Distance</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Intensity</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Trend</td>
                            <td style='background-color:#333; color:#3299cc; font-weight: normal; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>Last Strike</td
                        </tr>"; // break the top part of the table
// create your loop
for($k=0;$k<YOUR MAX ROWS;$k++){
         $tracreport .="<tr>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tid[$k] . "</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdtime[$k] . "</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdirection[$k] . "  &deg;</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . $tdistance[$k] . " miles</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" . strtolower($tintensity[$k]) . "</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" .  trim(strtolower($ttrend[$k])) . "</td>
                            <td style='background-color: black; color: #FFF; border: 1px #666 solid; text-align: center; font-size: .9em;'>" .  trim(strtolower($tactivity[$k])) . "</td>
                        </tr>";
}  // close your loop
   // finish your table
    $tracreport .= "</table>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
```

---

**edit**
instead of `for($k=0;$k<YOUR MAX ROWS;$k++){...}`, if you don't know the total max, use a foreach loop

```
foreach($tid as $k => $v){
  ...
}
```

this will then loop through each of the values without needing to know the max count

Comment: This works great and exactly what I am looking for but is it possible to have it add a new row as needed instead of setting max rows. Otherwise it shows unpopulated rows if there is not enough data to populate the rows for the number you have set.

Comment: Yes, the easiest would probably change to a foreach. I will edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to generate table rows:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $yourquery = mysql_query("");
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($yourquery)) {
        ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><?php $rows['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php $rows['age']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: This isn't using a database so that wouldn't work. The script reads a text file and populates the cells with variables it parses from the text file.